# LiveCycle Xml attribute binding

Tags: javascript, xml, binding, attributes, livecycle

I have a PDF template that I designed in Livecycle Designer. The data binding is Simple XML . For one of the fields I need to bind the data with an XML attribute.
For example: My xml:

```
<product>
       <price>
           <oldprice visible="true">

                <priceA visible="false">1.350,00</priceA>

                <priceB visible="true">1.350,00</priceB>

                <priceC visible="true">20,00</priceC>

                <priceD visible="false">0,00</priceD>

            </oldprice>

            <newprice visible="true">

                <priceA visible="false">1.350,00</priceA>

                <priceB visible="true">1.350,00</priceB>

                <priceC visible="true">20,00</priceC>

                <priceD visible="false">0,00</priceD>

            </newprice>

      </price>
</product>
```

How can I access the value of "visible" attribute?

I tried with:

xfa.resolveNode("product.price.oldprice.visible").rawValue;

but it doesn't work.

Can someone please help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming product is the root of your schema, you should be able to reference it like this:

```
xfa.datasets.data.product.price.oldprice.visible.value
```

.rawValue is for fields, if you want to get to data in the schema you use .value instead.

If product isn't the root node of the schema, then you need to include the root as well.

Comment: Thank you for your anwser. I must be doing something wrong, because the value of attributes is always empty (blank space). If I write .rawValue instead of .value the pdf shows the word "Empty" I have this Problem only with attributes, if I use a XML node I get the value without any Problems.